# Partially change a WPF template for a standard control

Tags: .net, wpf, templates, controls

I have a `TextBox` control placed inside my window and I would like to change its `Border`. In order to do this, I have to somehow modify the existing `Border` set by the default control template.

Is there a way to modify only a part of a default control template (for a standard WPF control) by somehow overriding the existing objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx

> There is no way to replace only part of the visual tree of a control; to change the visual tree of a control you must set the Template property of the control to its new and complete ControlTemplate.

Comment: Makes sense. Would it be possible to somehow obtain the default control template without using Microsoft Expression Blend?

Comment: That link I posted has links to the default templates, just scroll down the page a little

Comment: I've seen that. I was just curious if there is a way to somehow extract the existing template from a control directly from Visual Studio.